# requests.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:600)

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, ssl-certificate, python-requests

**This is not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35403605/ssl-certificate-verify-failed-ssl-c600)**

I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38522939/requests-exceptions-sslerror-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certificate-verif) but going insecure way doesn't looks good to me.

I am working on image size fetcher in python, which would fetch size of image on a web page. Before doing that I need to get web page status-code. I tried doing this way

```py
import requests

hdrs = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla / 5.0 (X11 Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit / 537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome / 52.0.2743.116 Safari / 537.36'}


urlResponse = requests.get(
    'http://aucoe.info/', verify=True, headers=hdrs)
print(urlResponse.status_code)
```

This gives error:

> ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify
>   failed (_ssl.c:600)

I tried changing `verify=True` to

`verify='/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt'`

and

`verify='/etc/ssl/certs'`

But it still gives the same error.
I need to get status code for more than 5000 urls. Kindly help me.
Thanks in advance.

**Python Version :** 3.4

**Requests version :** requests==2.11.1

**O.S :** Ubuntu 14.04

**pyOpenSSL :** 0.13

**openssl version :** OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to download the GoDaddy root certificates, available at [this site](https://certs.godaddy.com/repository) and then pass it in as a parameter to `verify`, like this:

```
>>> r = requests.get('https://aucoe.info', verify='/path/to/gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt')
>>> r.status_code
200
```

If you'll be doing multiple requests, you may want to configure the SSL as part of the session, as highlighted in the [documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#ssl-cert-verification).

Comment: Why godaddy ?
Is the domain registered with godaddy ?

Answer (score 2):

You can always set `verify= False`. Easy way, not the best.